# Data not shown in Django admin after adding by my form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am a beginner to Django.
I want to create a form that allow user to store their data to the database, but I face to an issue.

If I add data through Django admin, the data will shown correctly. But if I add data through my form. Data will store into database successfully but they don't shown in my Django admin.

Note: The Django version I used is 1.11.2

[The is my Django admin page. There are 8 data in the database but just show the one I added by the Django admin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pX3X.png)

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .forms import ApplyFormCreateForm
from .models import ApplyForm

class ApplyFormCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ApplyFormCreateForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
    success_url = "/"
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from course.models import Semester

DEFAULT_SEMESTER_ID = 1 

class ApplyForm(models.Model):
    name          = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    school        = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    department    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email         = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    is_beginner   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    introduction  = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    motivation    = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    comments      = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    semester      = models.ForeignKey(Semester, default=DEFAULT_SEMESTER_ID)
    created_at    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.school + self.department + self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school + self.department + self.name
```

**form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type='submit'>Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import ApplyForm

class ApplyFormCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ApplyForm
        fields = [
            'name',
            'school',
            'department',
            'email',
            'is_beginner',
            'introduction',
            'motivation',
            'comments',
        ]
```

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from myweb.views import HomeView
from course.views import CourseListView
from applyform.views import ApplyFormCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^course/$', CourseListView.as_view(), name='course'),
    url(r'^apply/$', ApplyFormCreateView.as_view(), name='applyform'),
]
```

Comment: Are they both pointing to the right database?

Comment: @ConorThompson yap! I can check the data via url directly. e.g via the url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/applyform/applyform/10/change/'.

Comment: It seems that the default value cause the issue. I don't put the "semester" field in the form and just assign the default value in my models.py. But in my admin.py, I put the 'semester' field in the list_display. When I remove the 'semester' field from the list_display, all data appear!!